# Failing OCUnit tests don't take me to the failing line when I click the error in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, ocunit, sentestingkit

I've got a large iOS project set up with OCUnit tests, some of which are imported from a dependent project, and some of which are local.  When I have a failing test in the dependent project, I can click the error, and be transported to the line that's breaking.  This isn't working for the local tests.  It just takes me to the file, but not the breaking line.

Does anyone know if there is something special I need to do in my unit tests, or configuration of XCode, to get jumping to the broken test working?

(I'm on XCode 4.6.2)

Comment: Do you use normal STAssertX macros?

Comment: And also, what do you mean with "a dependant project"? Are all your tests in the same test target?

Comment: I do use normal assert macros, and I mean that there is another XCode project in my workspace, that is a build dependency of the first project, so it builds automatically when I build the first project.

Answer (score 0):

It's not you. Xcode 4 doesn't correctly interpret relative paths like `proj1/foo/../../proj2/bar/file.m` for unit test failures.